# CSS Style Sheets -

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the versions one below the other but also with some tries I could not get it. This is my code:

```
<input type="text" 
               data-ng-model="file"
               typeahead="document as document.fileName for document in findDocumentsByTerm($viewValue)"
               typeahead-template-url = "documentContactTemplate.htm"  />
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="documentContactTemplate.htm">
                <div class="icon-hover">                    
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr data-ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
                            <td style="border:none;"><b>{{match.model.fileName}}</b></td>
                            <td style="border:none;"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
                            <td style="border:none;">
                                <div data-ng-repeat="documentFileVersion in match.model.documentFileVersions">
                                    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="selected" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" data-ng-click="match.model.vm.attachFile(selected, match.model, documentFileVersion)" /> {{documentFileVersion.version.substr(1)}}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </script>
```

and it looks like this:

[image: example]

Does anyone how I can get it to have the versions one below the other?

Comment: What do you mean in "the versions one below the other"?

Comment: Look at the image attached, App.png has two versions (1 and 2) and App Development.pdf has one version. My intention is that Version1 of App Development.pdf is exactly under Version1 and Version2 of App.png. Thanks!

Comment: So your goal is to not have your data display in a tabular format but at the same time use a element structure explicitly made to display data in a tabular format?

Comment: Why is the your html inside the `<script>` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to add `<thead>` in your table and set column's width.

```
<div class="icon-hover">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 60%"></th>
                <th style="width: 10%"></th>
                <th style="width: 30%"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
                <td style="border:none;"><b>{{match.model.fileName}}</b></td>
                <td style="border:none;"><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
                <td style="border:none;">
                    <div data-ng-repeat="documentFileVersion in match.model.documentFileVersions">
                        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="selected" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" data-ng-click="match.model.vm.attachFile(selected, match.model, documentFileVersion)" /> {{documentFileVersion.version.substr(1)}}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check this code which may be help you....

1.]please take one container inside repeater and place checkbox & label inside it.

### 2.]place vertical-align:top in "{{match.model.fileName}}" td..

please find attache code

```html
 <table class="table">
            <tr data-ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
                <td style="border: none;vertical-align:top">
                    <b>{{match.model.fileName}}</b>
                </td>
                <td style="border: none;">
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                </td>
                <td style="border: none;">
                    <div data-ng-repeat="documentFileVersion in match.model.documentFileVersions">
                        <div><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="selected" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"
                            data-ng-click="match.model.vm.attachFile(selected, match.model, documentFileVersion)" />
                        {{documentFileVersion.version.substr(1)}}</div>
                         <div><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="selected" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"
                            data-ng-click="match.model.vm.attachFile(selected, match.model, documentFileVersion)" />
                        {{documentFileVersion.version.substr(1)}}</div>
                         <div><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="selected" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"
                            data-ng-click="match.model.vm.attachFile(selected, match.model, documentFileVersion)" />
                        {{documentFileVersion.version.substr(1)}}</div>
                         <div><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="selected" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"
                            data-ng-click="match.model.vm.attachFile(selected, match.model, documentFileVersion)" />
                        {{documentFileVersion.version.substr(1)}}</div>
                         <div><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="selected" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"
                            data-ng-click="match.model.vm.attachFile(selected, match.model, documentFileVersion)" />
                        {{documentFileVersion.version.substr(1)}}</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```